# Does OAuth 1.0a "Work" When Service Provider Provides The Consumer

Tags: security, authentication, web, oauth, authorization

I am in the process of designing a RESTful API/web-service with the expectation that it will eventually be able to be consumed by several client web applications/consumers. As part of this service, I would like to have the first consumers be web browsers, in which the API/service provides a website that can access the API.

Is there a feasible/secure way in which OAuth 1.0a may be used for a Consumer (in this case, website) that is ultimately provided by the "same" service as the API itself?

Mainly, how can I ensure that this consumer has a valid secret Consume Key if it gets sent over the wire? Is there a way to "pre-register" an instance of the webpage, with its own Consumer Key, prior to sending?

(I plan on using HTTPS with this design.)

Any direct answers are appreciated, and any references to other online material that may answer my question(s) is also appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

During further research, I have found that one of the goals of OAuth 2.0 is to factor in a use-case that handles browser-based web applications.

In Oauth 2.0, browser-based applications are considered "public clients;" the specification has an Implicit Grant workflow to handle clients of this type. Public clients are clients that cannot ensure that a client identifier or client secret be kept secret, therefore, the Implicit Grant flow does not explicitly rely on the requirement that it have a client secret. Rather, the client pre-registers a redirect-URI with the authorization server prior to gaining access tokens.

So, in short, there isn't a good way to pass a client secret "over the wire" in a browser-based application. (Or at least not a good way that I have discovered.) Rather the OAuth 2.0 Implicit Grant workflow can be used instead.